# Typechain and @typechain/ethersv5 conflicting issue in hardhat

Tags: solidity, hardhat, hardhat-deploy, unittesting

I am trying to write test cases in hardhat using Typescript and Typechain. But when I try to compile the contracts using `npx hardhat compile`, it is asking me to install `@typechain/ethers-v5`. When I try to install the package, it is throwing an error that the `typechain` and `@typechain/ethers-v5` packages are conflicting. Can anyone resolve the issue?

**Error:**
[image]

**Packages:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from `hardhat-typechain` which hasn't been updated in over 2 years. (Roughly line 8 in your screenshot).

I recommend removing it in favor of the officially supported `@typechain/hardhat`.

Recent version of all three packages are compatible without peer dependency conflicts.

```
// packge.json
...
"@typechain/ethers-v5": "^10.1.0",
"@typechain/hardhat": "^6.1.2",
"typechain": "^8.1.0",
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found using hardhat toolbox a much easier way to do stuff. So I have changed my package files now.